# Convert automatically excel table formulas from explicit cell reference to structured cell reference?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel table with formulas such as

```
=M9-C9*10-D9*10-C9*H9/100
```

I want to convert these formulas to use structured cell references that use the table column names in the formulas, like this fake formula:

```
=[Sales Amount]-[Profit]*10-[Costs]*10-[Profit]*[Risk]/100*10-[Capital]*[Gross]/100
```

Is there a way to automatically convert all the explicit column names (M9) to use structured references ([Sales Amount]).

It is error prone to go through and manually do it.

(Info about [Using structured references with Excel tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e))

Comment: From what I understand from the article you reference, you have to do it manually. Or write a complex VB macro to do it (I would disadvice that as it can introduce more errors than you would like.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** you could iterate through the explicit cell-references you want to replace. Make sure to backup your file before playing around with this!

```
Sub replaceformulas2()
    Dim c As Object

    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        With c

            .Formula = Replace(.Formula, "$", "") 'delete the cell-fixation
            .Formula = Replace(.Formula, "E2", "Yourtable[Sales Amount]")
            .Formula = Replace(.Formula, "F2", "Yourtable[Profit]")
            ' ...and so on

        End With
    Next c
End Sub
```

**Note:**

- you can add more expressions to replace
- realize that you have to replace cells like `A10` or `BA5`  *before* replacing something like `A1` or `B5` for obvious reasons. The same goes for ranges like `A1:A100`.
- instead of `Selection.Cells` you might want to use something like `Table1.UsedRange.Cells` or `Table1.Range("A1:B100").Cells`
- you could `Debug.Print .Formula` first to get an overview over all the different formulas you have
- If you're fancy you could

  - loop over the table headers
  - get `A1`-coordinates of the header
  - replicate the `A1`-string you want to replace, say, by adjusting them to line 9 like in your example
  - replace any occurences of the to-replace string with the `.Value` of the header-cell
  - however, this might be too much of an effort for a one-time overhaul of a workbook

Comment: I was hoping to avoid manually converting the cell names to the corresponding column name, to avoid errors as there are multiple lengthy formulas.   And the table is 20 columns wide with the majority containing formulas.    Hoping to find something that can identify the explicit cell reference and convert it automatically to corresponding structured reference

Comment: i'm not sure there is a clean solution for this, but i tried to adjust the code to your needs as a starting point. Two important things to consider: **i.** has your table more than one line, meaning one cell is referenced as a single cell AND as a range in another formula? e.g. one contains `=M9` and another `=SUM(M9:M100)`? b) are there any cells fixed with `$`?

Comment: ok thanks very much for suggestions.  The .Formula looks really promising!  I will play around with it ( on a copy of course :)).   I think it would be handy to have as I can see it coming up now and then.

Comment: glad i could help!

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a while ago, but I just solved this. And I thought I would share how.

First convert your data into a Table.  (If you want you can create more than one table, but you will need to then specify the table name as part of the reference further down this sequence).

In a separate sheet I created a reference table with two columns consisting of old references and new references.  To generate the old references I used an equation for the columns:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","")
```

And then concatenated it to the number of the first row.

[Thanks:  https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/857983-how-to-return-the-column-letter-of-cell-reference.html]

For the second column I used `copy and paste special; values; transpose` from the headings of the table where I wanted to create the structured references.

Then I used the macro `Sub Multi_FindReplace()` from here:
https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/14/find-and-replace-all

and that's it. Done for the first row. Then I could just fill down the rows to complete the table.

(Note, if you have fixed references (ie using `$`) then you might need to remove those first as they aren't needed in the structured referencing. If you need the fixed references to locations outside the table, you can use a variation of the above process to put them back in if you accidentally removed them. )