# VBA updating R1C1 formula to table formula

Tags: excel, vba, structured-references

I just started with a new company and checking their VBA codes and I noticed that they haven't been using table references and were using R1C1 references.

Is there a way for Excel to update automatically so that the code changes all R1C1 references to table form (i.e. `IF([@[Line of Business]]=""Motor"",[@Product],[@LOB])`)?

Comment: There is no way for Excel to know if a specific formula is or is not meant to apply to entire column via a structured reference. You may convert them [semi-manually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40839423/11683).

Comment: No no you didn't get what i meant. I want to change all the R1C1 formulas to ex @table [column] . Is there a way for excel to do it automatically when i recreate the table?